# Cocoapods Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`

Tags: git, cocoapods

I am having trouble installing new dependencies using pods.

Every time I add dependency in Podfile and hit `pod update`, I get an error `Unable to add a source with url`https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`named`master-1`.`.

I reinstalled cocoapods but no luck and there is only master folder present in ~/cocoapods/repo. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Cocoapods wasn't enough. I had to update git to get it working. Everything works now!